# Changing Limits on an Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I show

$$ \int_{t_0}^t \int_{t_0}^t H(t')H(t'') \, dt'' \, dt'= \int_{t_0}^t \int_{t_0}^{t'} [H(t')H(t'') + H(t'')H(t') ]\,dt''\,dt' ?$$

Starting with $ \int_{t_0}^t \int_{t_0}^t H(t')H(t'') \, dt'' \, dt'$ and writing it as
$$ \int_{t_0}^t \int_{t_0}^{t'} H(t')H(t'') \,dt'' \, dt' + \int_{t_0}^t \int_{t'}^t H(t')H(t'') \, dt'' \, dt'$$

what do I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the square $(x,y):0\leq x\leq t,0\leq y\leq t$.  The second integral is $$\int_{S,t''>t'}H(t')H(t'')dt''dt'$$
If you are allowed to change the order of integration, that becomes
$$\int_{S,t''>t'}H(t')H(t'')dt'dt''$$
Then rename $t'$ and $t''$
$$\int_{S,t'>t''}H(t')H(t'')dt''dt'$$
and turn it back to the double integral.